# Javascript code not giving any result

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

A `days` node with more than 1 child isn't getting removed. How can I fix this issue?

```
const theRef = event.data.ref;
const collectionRef = theRef.parent.child('days');
return collectionRef;
collectionRef.once('value').then(messagesData => {
  if(messagesData.numChildren() > 1) {
    let updates = {};
    updates['/days'] = null;
    return defaultDatabase.ref().update(updates); // 'days' doesn't get removed even if it has more than 1 child (as in the image)!
  } 
});
```

Data structure:

[image]

Comment: `});` is missing at the end.

Comment: @zuluk That's my mistake when copy/pasting.

Comment: @zuluk I corrected it. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

is it because you need to return collectionRef at the end not before calling once on collectionref?? so:

```
const theRef = event.data.ref;
const collectionRef = theRef.parent.child('days');

collectionRef.once('value').then(messagesData => {
  if(messagesData.numChildren() > 1) {
    let updates = {};
    updates['/days'] = null;
    return defaultDatabase.ref().update(updates); // 'days' doesn't get removed even if it has more than 1 child (as in the image)!
  } 
});

return collectionRef;
```